# Is there a way to annotate each point on a scatter with a list of strings?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter, annotate

I have made a scatter plot by using `variable=plt.scatter(test1,test2)` where `test1` and `test2` are lists corresponding to x and y.

Is there a way to annotate each point with a list of strings or variable color, that I have created?

I have found that:

```
for i, txt in enumerate(variablelabel):
    variable.annotate(txt, (test1[i],test2[i]))
```

where `variablelabel` is defined as my list of strings. Unfortunately, this does not seem to annotate my scatter plot.

Alternatively, I have found you can add arrows using this similar code:

```
ax.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),
arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

But this creates large arrows which I do not want. I only want strings from my list.

Sorry if I'm not being very clear.

Comment: Hacky solution would be to call annotate and pass arrowprops=None.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can annotate each point with a list of strings. Use [`matplotlib.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) is the solution. However you call `annotate` on a [`matplotlib.collections.PathCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection) object (result of [matplotlib.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html)) instead of a [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) object.

In your code:

```
variable = plt.scatter(test1, test2)
for i, txt in enumerate(variablelabel):
    variable.annotate(txt, (test1[i], test2[i]))
```

`variable` is a [`matplotlib.collections.PathCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection). Instead use the following:

```
plt.scatter(test1, test2)
for i, txt in enumerate(variablelabel):
    plt.annotate(txt, (test1[i], test2[i]))
```

You should get something like this:

[image]

I hope this will help you.

Comment: how can you prevent the text of the various annotations from overlapping?